# Rename [black-adder] to [blackadder]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I spotted earlier that the tag for [Blackadder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackadder) is [black-adder](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-adder) rather than [blackadder](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackadder).

The only time in the show's history the names are separated is in Series 1 which is called [The Black Adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Adder), however every subsequent series has it written as Blackadder in both the title and name of the Character:

- Lord Edmund Blackadder in [Blackadder II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackadder_II)
- Mr. Edmund Blackadder in [Blackadder the Third](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackadder_the_Third)
- Captain Edmund Blackadder in [Blackadder Goes Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackadder_Goes_Forth)

And so on in all the specials. There's a fair few questions so could we have the tag renamed and maybe [black-adder](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-adder) added as a synonym as it's a subcategory of Blackadder the series.

Comment: You have a cunning plan m'lord. I agree

Comment: damn, I'm feeling nostalgic ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the encompassing series name is indeed Blackadder.

I have made [black-adder](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-adder) a synonym of the new [blackadder](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackadder) tag.